# Abrir e fechar menu

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte menu, que funciona quando a tela está com *width: 768px* ou menor.
Quando eu clico no **fa-bars**, ele desaparece e mostra o **fa-times**. Abrindo o menu. Até aí tudo certo. 
Quero que quando eu clique no **fa-bars** ele esconda o menu novamente e mostre o **fa-bars**.

```js
$('header nav div.menuMobile').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('header nav div.menuMobile ul').show(300);
  $('.fa-bars').hide(300);
  $('.fa-times').show(300);
});

$('.fa-times').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('header nav div.menuMobile ul').show(300);
  $('.fa-times').hide(300);
  $('.fa-bars').show(300);
});
```

```css
header nav ul,
header nav a img {
  display: none
}

.menuMobile {
  display: block
}

.menuMobileClose {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menuMobile">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i style="display:none" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <img src="assets/images/layout/logo.png">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link">Quem Somos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link">E-commerce</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">Plataformas E-commerce</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Lojas virtuais customizadas</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Solução virtual para venda</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz este exemplo com algumas mudanças básicas. Dê mais foco nas minhas mudanças do JS porque de restante eu tive que mudar do seu código para funcionar aqui no site. Eu retirei também o logo porque era uma imagem quebrada que estava em cima do menu.

```js
$('.fa-bars').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('header nav div.menuMobile ul').show(300);
  $('.fa-bars').hide(300);
  $('.fa-times').show(300);
});

$('.fa-times').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('header nav div.menuMobile ul').hide(300);
  $('.fa-times').hide(300);
  $('.fa-bars').show(300);
});
```

```css
header nav ul,
header nav a img {
  display: none
}

.menuMobile {
  display: block
}

.menuMobileClose {
  display: block
}

div.fa-times {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.fa-bars {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menuMobile">
      <div class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></div>
      <div style="display:none" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link">Quem Somos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link">E-commerce</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">Plataformas E-commerce</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Lojas virtuais customizadas</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Solução virtual para venda</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```